# SQL to find the number of distinct values in a column

Tags: sql, distinct

I can select all the distinct values in a column in the following ways:

- `SELECT DISTINCT column_name FROM table_name;`
- `SELECT column_name FROM table_name GROUP BY column_name;`

But how do I get the row count from that query? Is a subquery required?

Comment: Check my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/75068192/8614314

Answer (score 742, accepted):

You can use the `DISTINCT` keyword within the [`COUNT`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175997%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) aggregate function:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT column_name) AS some_alias FROM table_name
```

This will count only the distinct values for that column.

Comment: Neat, i didn't know you could put the distinct keyword there.

Comment: also works on groups `select A,COUNT(DISTINCT B) from table group by A`

Comment: can you expand this example to distinct on multiple columns?

Comment: How do you store this some_alias in a new column because I want to use where condition on this some_alias but unable without creating a new column. when I try to add it in a new column it says Error: aggregate functions are not allowed in UPDATE

Answer (score 241):

This will give you BOTH the distinct column values and the count of each value.  I usually find that I want to know both pieces of information.

```
SELECT [columnName], count([columnName]) AS CountOf
FROM [tableName]
GROUP BY [columnName]
```

Answer (score 38):

An sql sum of column_name's unique values and sorted by the frequency:

```
SELECT column_name, COUNT(*) FROM table_name GROUP BY column_name ORDER BY 2 DESC;
```

Answer (score 31):

Be aware that Count() ignores null values, so if you need to allow for null as its own distinct value you can do something tricky like:

```
select count(distinct my_col)
       + count(distinct Case when my_col is null then 1 else null end)
from my_table
/
```

Comment: I really think your case statement was meant to say: `case when my_col is null then 1 else my_col end`

Comment: For clarity: ```SELECT my_col, COUNT(my_col) + COUNT(CASE WHEN my_col IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) as CountOf from my_Table GROUP BY my_col```

Comment: count(*) includes nulls

Comment: @PragmaticProgrammer I guess so, but there's not such a thing as a null row, only a null value, and `count(*)` is specifically a count of rows.

Answer (score 15):

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT column_name) FROM table as column_name_count;
```

you've got to count that distinct col, then give it an alias.

Answer (score 14):

```
select count(*) from 
(
SELECT distinct column1,column2,column3,column4 FROM abcd
) T
```

This will give count of distinct group of columns.

Answer (score 12):

```
select Count(distinct columnName) as columnNameCount from tableName
```

Answer (score 2):

To do this in [Presto using `OVER`](https://prestodb.io/docs/0.217/functions/window.html):

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT my_col,
                count(*) OVER (PARTITION BY my_col
                               ORDER BY my_col) AS num_rows
FROM my_tbl
```

Using this `OVER` based approach is of course optional. In the above SQL, I found specifying `DISTINCT` and `ORDER BY` to be necessary.

Caution: As per the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/performance-tuning.html#performance-tuning-use-more-efficient-functions), using `GROUP BY` may be more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

Using following SQL we can get the **distinct column value count** in Oracle 11g.

```
select count(distinct(Column_Name)) from TableName
```

Answer (score 1):

After MS SQL Server 2012, you can use window function too.

```
SELECT column_name, COUNT(column_name) OVER (PARTITION BY column_name) 
FROM table_name
GROUP BY column_name
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this.

```
Select distinct PRODUCT_NAME_X 
,count (Product_name) products_# 
from TableX
Group by PRODUCT_NAME
```

It will return

```
PRODUCT_NAME    products
XXXXXXXXXX      4760
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select count(distinct(column_name)) AS columndatacount from table_name where somecondition=true
```

You can use this query, to count different/distinct data.

Answer (score 0):

Without using DISTINCT this is how we could do it-

```
SELECT COUNT(C)
FROM (SELECT COUNT(column_name) as C
FROM table_name
GROUP BY column_name)
```

Answer (score -10):

Count(distinct({fieldname})) is redundant

Simply Count({fieldname}) gives you all the distinct values in that table. It will not (as many presume) just give you the Count of the table [i.e. NOT the same as Count(*) from table]

Comment: No, this is *not* correct. `count(field)` returns the number of lines where `field` is `not null`.