# sql-server, count rows where column matches string and id is not repeated

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following table in sql-server database:

[image]

I want to count the total number of rows where the column (state = Alabama and ID is not repeated).

For this example from Alabama is 2.

And I want to count the number of ID's that are repeated (here it is 2).

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL to find the number of distinct values in a column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/141562/sql-to-find-the-number-of-distinct-values-in-a-column)

Comment: Not the same problem. I don't want just to count number of distinct ID's.

Comment: What do you mean with `where ID is not repeated`? Do you only need IDs 101 and 105?

Comment: Now I get it, you want the count of the IDs that have only the State Alabama and not anything else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT count(id), state
FROM table_name
WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM table_name GROUP BY id having count(id) = 1) and state = 'Alabama'
GROUP BY state
```

Comment: You'll want to include `AND State='Alabama'`

Comment: @NickyvV This query gives count of all the states. Anyways will change it.

Comment: What about the number of id's that are duplicated? Could you please help?

Answer (score 1):

use

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ID) AS id FROM MYTABLE where State = 'Alabama'
```

if you need count of id's that are repeated

```
 SELECT COUNT(ID) AS id FROM MYTABLE where ID= '105'
```

Comment: I don't want to count Alabama where it is in duplicate ID

Comment: @SherzodMuminov:is the edited one is what you intended ?

Answer (score 1):

```
  select count(*), State from Table
 where ID in
        (select ID from Table group bu ID having count(*)=1) and State is 'Alabama'
 group by State
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @test TABLE  
    (
     id int , 
     name varchar(20) 
    );

INSERT INTO @test VALUES (101,'Albama');
INSERT INTO @test VALUES (102,'Montana');
INSERT INTO @test VALUES (103,'Montana');
INSERT INTO @test VALUES (104,'Albama');
INSERT INTO @test VALUES (105,'Albama');
INSERT INTO @test VALUES (105,'Albama');

WITH  CTE AS
(
select id,name,ROW_NUMBER()OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY NAME DESC) AS RN from @test
)
select COUNT(id),name from CTE WHERE NAME =  CASE WHEN ID = 105 THEN name ELSE NAME END
GROUP BY NAME
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Create Table myTable ( [ID] [int], [State] [nvarchar](255) );

INSERT INTO myTable(ID,[State]) VALUES(101,'Alabama');
INSERT INTO myTable(ID,[State]) VALUES(102,'Montana');
INSERT INTO myTable(ID,[State]) VALUES(103,'Monatana');
INSERT INTO myTable(ID,[State]) VALUES(103,'Alabama');
INSERT INTO myTable(ID,[State]) VALUES(104,'Alabama');
INSERT INTO myTable(ID,[State]) VALUES(105,'Monatana');
INSERT INTO myTable(ID,[State]) VALUES(105,'Alabama');
```

Use the below Query to get the required result.

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ID) AS ID, [State]
FROM myTable
WHERE ID IN (SELECT ID FROM myTable GROUP BY ID having COUNT(ID) = 1) and [State] = 'Alabama'
GROUP BY [State]
```

[Live SQL SERVER Fiddle Here.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d99cc/3)

Comment: What about the number of id's that are duplicated? Could you please help?

Comment: By using this query you always gets the unique and distinct records. This query will ignore the repeating Ids. The resultant of this query is based on, 101 and 104 Ids. The record with repeated Ids will be skip in the resultant

Comment: This is your statement **I don't want to count Alabama where it is in duplicate ID**. The provided solution is based on your requirements that you have given.