# How to find how many different words there are in a column in sql?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

If I have a table like so:

- Apple
- Orange
- Pear
- Pear
- Orange

How do I  view how many different words there are?
In this example it would be three:

1. Apple
2. Orange
3. Pear

Comment: Hint:  `group by` or `select distinct`.

Comment: If I understood it weel, you want an SQL to count the distinct fruits.

Comment: Can you pls show me an example as to how select distinct would be used? @GordonLinoff

Comment: @EddeAlmeida That is correct

Comment: Then all you need is a SELECT DISTINCT. See this: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-distinct-keyword.htm

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL to find the number of distinct values in a column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/141562/sql-to-find-the-number-of-distinct-values-in-a-column)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT column_name) AS some_alias FROM table_name
```

Comment: If I had "Apples, Oranges" in one row. Would it be possible to split the fruits into two between the commas?

Comment: well, you can't do that with the query above as it will look for the whole string "Apples, Oranges". Maybe you can do some pre-processing before running the query?

Answer (score 1):

1. To get the no. of diff  words you can use either `group by` or `distinct`.
   `select words_column_name, count(words_column_name) as no_of_repetation from table_name group by words_column_name`.
   or just `select distinct(words_column_name) from table_name`

2.To split the word, there is no in build function, but you can do it using substring() & locate().  like:

```
SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(fullword, ',', 1), ',', -1) AS first_fruit,
    TRIM( SUBSTR(fullname, LOCATE(',', fullword)) ) AS last_fruit
```

But this is applicable only for 2 fruit combination, for more you need to write some php script or mysql function