# Trying to find distinct rows as a percentage for multiple columns in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

So I am extremely new to SQL, I know the basics but this one is a hard one I guess :)

I have an assignment where I need to find the distinct rows in each column as a % (the query should be able to determine the % of rows in that particular column that are distinct) and this needs to be done for multiple columns. I have to do more but I'll save that once I figure this out.

Can someone please help me out. A starting point would be nice.

Appreciate the help!!

Comment: Is this MySQL or SQL Server? It can't be both.

Comment: A starting point would be to use aggregates. Things like COUNT and some basic math should get you going.

Comment: Look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/141562/sql-to-find-the-number-of-distinct-values-in-a-column).

Comment: SQL Server.....

Comment: @Sean Lange, I did look at it before posting the question. Through your guide I was able to query for distinct rows in a column. However, it doesn't have a solution to my second problem. Displaying the distinct rows as a percentage and doing the same for multiple columns in the same query.

Answer (score 1):

I would go as simple as this, I don't think your teacher wants you to mess up with specifics of SQL-Server if you are learning SQL:

```
select (100.0*count(distinct MyFirstColumn))/count(*) as FirstPercentage, 
       (100.0*count(distinct MySecondColumn))/count(*) as secondPercentage
from MyTable
```

Notice the extra `100.0 *` product, to make it an actual percentage, the `.0` will make it a decimal number, otherwise you'll get an integer division which would result in 0

Comment: Thank you so much Roberto. That really helped.

Comment: Is there also a way to compare columns ? So I have 10 columns in total , I want to calculate the distinct % of each but also compare each column and return the column which has the highest % of distinct values.

Answer (score 0):

There is no straight forward answer for this question in TSQL  but there are so many tolls

If you are using SSIS this can be easily archive usning [Data Profiling Task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/control-flow/data-profiling-task-and-viewer) with [Column Value Distribution Profile Request Options (Data Profiling Task)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/control-flow/column-value-distribution-profile-request-options-data-profiling-task) Or use any another data profiling tool like Datamartist...

Comment: So there is no way I can write a query for this is SQL Server? It's more of an assignment and the teacher wants to see my logic. I know I can use DISTINCT for just querying the unique values in a column, but what would the percentage clause?

Comment: it will not be straight forward you have to write row count for each column and in temp tables and then do aggregation and all stuf

Comment: This is just a school project to learn some basic t-sql. I would disagree there is no straight forward way to do this in t-sql. In fact it is quite easy. I think you are way over complicating the requirements here.