# Get count and list of unique values from table without listing each column using SQL in QGIS

Tags: sql, qgis

Based on questions like [SQL to find the number of distinct values in a column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/141562/sql-to-find-the-number-of-distinct-values-in-a-column) and https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/330932/get-line-length-using-sql-in-qgis

I see we can get a count and list of unique values using SQL but I can't see anything where we can do this without knowing the name of the field.

**Is it possible in SQL for QGIS which only allows [these commands](https://sqlite.org/lang.html)?** I found this option for another flavor -https://dataedo.com/kb/query/sql-server/list-table-columns-in-database

In Mapbasic I have used the following but would like to do this in SQL...

```
'Get Column Name list
dim x as integer
dim sColName as string
dim aColName as Alias
For x=1 to TableInfo(temptable, TAB_INFO_NCOLS)
    sColName = ColumnInfo(temptable, "col"+str$(x), COL_INFO_NAME)
    if (sColName not in ("GID","GID_New")) then
        aColName = sColName

        Select aColName, count(*) from temptable group by aColName into "g_"+sColName
        Browse * from "g_"+sColName
        Export "g_"+sColName Into WFolder+RSelection.col2+"_"+sColName+".csv" Type "ASCII" Delimiter "," CharSet "WindowsLatin1" Titles
    End If
Next
```

I guess in SQL we would use http://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-basics/sql-server-select-distinct/ but how can I tell it to just use every column in the table without knowing/specifying the name?

UPDATE

If I run

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM Drainage_Lines_Clip;
```

I get
[image]

But I need something like the following without having to specify the column name. [Ref](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30338143/730265)
[image]

It should look like this extract from running Unique on a google sheet of the data (except with counts)
[image]

Comment: What flavour of SQL are you using? And would you be open to using dynamic SQL if required?

Comment: And have you tried using SELECT DISTINCT * FROM <YourTable> ?

Comment: Yes [SELECT DISTINCT     * FROM     Drainage_Lines_Clip;] does list unique for each column but then repeats a value when there aren't enough unique values in the column. If QGIS can handle dynamic SQL that would be fine.

Comment: What do you mean it does list unique values but then repeats a value?

Comment: Sorry - I have updated the question with details.

Comment: How do you know which column to get if you can't specify a name?

Comment: I want to get all of them but ideally have a list where it doesn't get a unique value if it's in the list. The mapbasic code does this in the following line - if (sColName not in ("GID","GID_New")) then

Comment: OOohhh it generates all of the columns with the count. I've got an idea, but it will need dynamic SQL. Bear with, I'll post an answer shortly.

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: I am using SQL within QGIS on flat spatial files - not sure what it does/doesn't allow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up having to use a combination of PyQGIS and SQL to get what's needed.

```
layer = qgis.utils.iface.activeLayer()
fields=[] # List of fields
Lquery=[] # List of queries to join together with Union All statement
Cquery=[] # Combined Query to use
for field in layer.fields():
    if field.name() not in ('GID_New'):
        fields.append(field.name())
        query = "Select '{0}' as 'Column', {0} as 'Value', count(*) as 'Unique' from {1} group by {0}".format(field.name(), layer.name())
        Lquery.append(query)
    else:
        print (field.name())
#    query = "Select {0}, count(*) from {1} group by {0} order by 2 Desc".format(field.name(), layer.name())

for L in Lquery:
    Cquery.append(L+' Union All ')
query=''.join(map(str, Fquery))
query=query[:-11]+' Order by Column'
vlayer = QgsVectorLayer( "?query={}".format(query), 'counts_'+layer.name(), "virtual" )
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(vlayer)
```

Answer (score 1):

So this answer is based upon dynamic SQL. You'll get people saying 'don't use it it's dangerous', but they're the kind of people that think the best access to a system for users is none.. Anyway. Be aware of the security risks with SQL injection when using dynamic SQL. I'll leave that part up to you..

The below goes off to the sys.columns table and grabs all of the column names in the table, then a SQL statement is constructed to count all of the values in each column in your target table.

```
DECLARE @ReturnVar NVARCHAR(MAX);

SELECT @ReturnVar = COALESCE(@ReturnVar + ' UNION ALL ', '') + 'SELECT ''' + c.[name] + ''' [ColumnName], CAST(' + c.[name] + ' AS VARCHAR(MAX)) [ColumnValue], CAST(COUNT(1) AS VARCHAR(MAX)) [Count] FROM dbo.Admissions GROUP BY  CAST(' + c.[name] + ' AS VARCHAR(MAX))'
FROM sys.columns c
INNER JOIN sys.objects o ON o.object_id = c.object_id
INNER JOIN sys.schemas s ON s.schema_id = o.schema_id
WHERE o.[name] = 'Drainage_Lines_Clip'
AND s.[name] = 'dbo'
AND c.[name] != 'GID_New';

EXEC sp_executesql @ReturnVar;
```

Comment: I get an error -it's probably since this is a flat geospatial file and not a postgis database. So it's not dbo.Drainage_Lines.Clip.GID_New for example. The error is [Query execution error on CREATE TEMP VIEW _tview AS DECLARE @ReturnVar NVARCHAR(MAX);  EXEC sp_executesql @ReturnVar;: 1 - near "DECLARE": syntax error]

Comment: Ohh. I've just realised your not using a database, just an interpreter over a flat file. My answer won't apply then as it's only for SQL Server. What software are you using to run the SQL query?

Comment: QGIS.org - I've been trying to locate some info on the flavor of SQL and commands it allows but haven't been able to.

Comment: Based on the following post I think it's https://sqlite.org/lang.html and https://www.gaia-gis.it/fossil/libspatialite/index -- So Select Spatialite_version() gives me Spatialite_version() = 4.3.0 -- Ref:  https://medium.com/@GispoFinland/learn-spatial-sql-and-master-geopackage-with-qgis-3-16b1e17f0291

Comment: I've had a play around, but I can't figure it out. Here's the fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/320e4/21 I get the feeling sqllite isnt meant for what we're trying to do. You could fire a query using python though, that would work..

Comment: Thanks - this is what I'm trying now - so 
---
query = """Select Material, count(*) from Sewerage_Manholes_InspectionShafts group by Material order by 2 Desc""" 
vlayer = QgsVectorLayer( "?query={}".format(query), "vlayer", "virtual" )
---
Does the needful and I'll just have to wrap it in a script that get's the table column names and parses it to the sql command and build up the table.