# Inquiries about a specific period

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I want a query ms_access in vb.net to search between two different times.
Compilation of the drug items in quantities during the period for each group

[image]

My attempt does not do what is required.
The sum is shown for all the elements together, not each element.
[image]

```
  Dim A = Format(DATETIM_START.Value, "yyyy/MM/dd")
            Dim B = Format(DATETIM_END.Value, "yyyy/MM/dd")
            Select    MEDICALPRO_NAME ,(Select SUM(MEDICALPRO_LEAVEM) FROM MEDICALPRO_TB Where MEDICALPRO_CHECK = True    And (((MEDICALPRO_DATEEND) between #" & B & "# And #" & A & "#))  ) As Total_quantities  FROM MEDICALPRO_TB  GROUP BY MEDICALPRO_NAME"
```

Comment: Please post the actual code you're running as what you've posted isn't valid VB.net code. Please also don't convert Dates to strings and then insert the strings into a SQL query. Then learn about parametrized queries and use them always.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL to find the number of distinct values in a column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/141562/sql-to-find-the-number-of-distinct-values-in-a-column)

Comment: Looks like a simple aggregate (TOTALS) query to me. Use Access query builder to get the correct SQL structure then transfer that to the code.