# How to retrieve distinct values in an order from the MySQL database?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table in the database that i'd like to retrieve distinct values in an order from the oldest to the most recent.

The closest result I got was this using this sql command:

```
SELECT userID FROM commande ORDER BY date_commande ASC, userID ASC;
```

```
userID
1
1
2
2
3
3
2
1
1
2
2
```

As you can see, the values are repetitive, i want to get a result that doesn't repeat when the items I retrieve have the same userID and datetime:

```
userID
1
2
3
2
1
2
```

I appreciate your help,

Full table:
[Name of the table: Commande](https://i.stack.imgur.com/izBdZ.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL to find the number of distinct values in a column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/141562/sql-to-find-the-number-of-distinct-values-in-a-column)

Comment: If a userID has several dates, which of them should be ordered by?

Comment: @jarlh

basically, if the userID have the same dates, then it only shows one of them and then orders from oldest to most recent

Comment: @mmh4all

Thanks for your reply,

Unfortunately, it doesn't answer my question

Comment: Provide source data which produces shown output as INSERT INTO code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT userID 
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT userID, date_commande
    FROM commande 
    ) subquery
ORDER BY date_commande ASC, userID ASC;
```